# How to customize property names in javers

Tags: javers

Is there anyway we can customize the property names of an entity?

There is an annotation @TypeName for modifying the class name.

Is there any specific annotation for fields ?

Comment: there is no such feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javers 3.1.0, the `@PropertyName` annotation can be used to easily customize property names.

`@PropertyName` — gives an arbitrary name to a property. When not found, Javers infers a property name from a field or getter name. @PropertyName could be useful when refactoring clases that are already committed to JaversRepository.

see https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#supported-annotations

Comment: Are you still planning this option?

Comment: This feature is still waiting for a contributor https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/403

Comment: @BartekWalacik - Have you implemented this annotation now ? Or still in planning phase ?